# how to change iframe src with select option?

Tags: html, iframe

**I guess you can see the idea i have ;) how can i make this work? Thanks ;)**

```
<select name="test" onchange="myFunction();" >
  <option value="index.html">Home</option>
  <option vaule="contact.html">Contact</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("iframe").src = 'test.value';
}
</script>


<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sel.value` property

Here the code i would use:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  sel = document.getElementById("sel")
  if(sel.value === "index.html"){
      document.getElementById("iframe").src =    
'https://link';
  } else {
      document.getElementById("iframe").src = 
'https://anotherLink';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

easy just target your selectbox and get it's value using `querySelector`

try the snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
var val = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]').options;
document.getElementById("iframe").src = val[val.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(document.getElementById("iframe").src);
}
```

```html
<select name="test" onchange="myFunction();" >
  <option value="index.html">Home</option>
  <option value="contact.html">Contact</option>
</select>




<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```